# Why zc fold all the sections at the first time?

Tags: folding

I have just the following two lines in `~/vimrc` to set vim's `foldmethod` to `marker`. I do not want all sections are collapsed when the document is opened. So I use `nofoldenable` to open all marked sections in the document. It shows just like a normal document without folding.

```
setlocal foldmethod=marker
setlocal nofoldenable
```

Then I open a document with several fold-marked sections. We may use the following simple document as illustration.

```
{{{
fold-marked section one
}}}
plain text
{{{
fold-marked section two
}}}
```

When I hit `zc`, all the sections are collapsed. While in the documentation, it says `zc` should fold only the section under the cursor. I am in normal mode, not in visual mode. I am not highlighting or selecting any text neither.

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/fold.html#fold-commands

```
                            *zc*
zc      Close one fold under the cursor.  When a count is given, that
        many folds deep are closed.  In Visual mode one level of folds
        is closed for all lines in the selected area.
        'foldenable' will be set.
```

After all sections are folded, we can use `zr` to unfold all the sections. After that, `zc` behaves as expected. Pressing `zc` folds only the one section under the cursor.

May I ask why `zc` behaves abnormally at the first time whenever a document is opened?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Possibly `zc` has to toggle foldenable which may trigger folding based on the current foldlevel (? I think that’s the right term)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble - Yea I guess this may be the reason.